# Setting SQL statement parameter value not being replaced with value correctly

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am building SQL query in my Java code as follows:

```
return "where 1 = 1" +
        (!isNullOrEmpty(model.getAccount()) ? " and a.accounts ->> 'id' = :id " : "") +
```

I need to change the form from `a.accounts ->> 'id' = ?` to `a.accounts @> '{"id": "XXXX"}'`

So I tried:

```
 return "where 1 = 1" +
                (!isNullOrEmpty(search.getAccount()) ? " and a.accounts @> '{\"id\": \":id\"}' " : "") +
```

but this doesn't replace the param `id`.

Can someone help with what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works:

```
public List<Person> findWithContains(int id) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("accounts", "{ \"id\": " + id + " }");

    return template.query(
            "select * from people where accounts @> CAST(:accounts as jsonb)", 
            params,
            new PersonRowMapper());
}
```

Comment: I’m using bean value property  mapper

Comment: If i am understanding ok, you are using PostgreSQL and a.accounts should contains { "id": ?, other fields } ?

Comment: What about using a Map<String, Object> for that parameter

Comment: Something like: Map<String, Object> parameters;
parameters.put("id", 1);